# Add bottom border, after adding inner borders, to Table CSS

Tags: html, css

Hello  I want to add borders inside a table, and in the bottom of the table.  With what i found, i was able to add the inner borders, however, i am getting trouble in adding also the bottom border. How can i do it ?

My table

```
  <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    
      <th>Produto</th>
      <th>Quantidade</th>
      <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="c in compras">
      
      <td>{{c.nome}}</td>
      <td>{{c.qtd}}</td>
      <td>{{c.valor}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the Css i have, that managed to fill the inner borders

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style: hidden;
}

table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

exactly the same which you used for the inners